# dynamically create greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, dynamic, greasemonkey, window.open

I'm trying to create a dynamic GM script. Here's what I thought would do it

```
win = window.open('myScript.user.js');
win.document.writeln('// ==UserScript==');
win.document.writeln('// @name          sample script');
win.document.writeln('// @description   alerts hi');
win.document.writeln('// @include       http://www.google.com/*');
win.document.writeln('// ==/UserScript==');
win.document.writeln('');
win.document.writeln('(function(){alert("hi");})()');
win.document.close();
```

Well it doesn't. Anyone have any ideas how to go about doing this?

Comment: window.open doesn't work with .js files use html instead and wrap your code with a <script> tag

Comment: it's wrapped in an onclick event so it opens the window just not the way I'd like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically create Greasemonkey scripts with Greasemonkey (alone).

A GM script is not part of the HTML page, so writing GM code to a page will never work.   The script needs to be installed into GM's script management system.

A GM script cannot write to the file system, nor access sufficient browser chrome to install a script add-on.

- You *might* be able to write a GM script that posts other scripts to a server, and then sends the browser to that server.   GM would then prompt the user to install the new script.
- You *might* be able to write a browser add-on that could write GM scripts, but I suspect that this approach will be difficult.
- You probably could write a Python (or C, VB, etc.) program that generates GM scripts for installation.  With extra work, such a program could probably automatically install the script, too.

---

Why do you want to dynamically create Greasemonkey scripts, anyway?  There may be a simpler method to accomplish the true goal.?.

---

---

### Update for OP comment/clarification:

Re: `"I want to be able to have a user select an element to get blocked and then create a script that sets that element's display to none on all sites from that domain"`...

One way to do that:

1. Store domain and selector pairs using [GM_setValue()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).
2. The script would, first thing, check to see if it had a value stored for the current page's domain or URL (using [GM_getValue() or GM_listValues()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual%3aAPI)).
3. If a match was found, hide the element(s) as specified in the selector.

Note that, depending on the element, the excellent [Adblock Plus extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) may be able to block the element much more elegantly (saves bandwidth/DL-time too).

Comment: I want to be able to have a user select an element to get blocked and then create a script that sets that element's display to none on all sites from that domain

Comment: I've updated my answer to outline way(s) to do that, that don't require dynamic scripts.